# Mod_Rewrite rule doesn't seem to be working with server queries

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

I've been wrestling with a mod_rewrite rule that doesn't seem to be working. Briefly, I want the following URL:
www.servername.com/showtest/1
to redirect to:
www.servername.com/showtest.php?id=1

I thought the following in my .htaccess should get the redirect working:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^showevent/(\w+)/?$  showevent.php?id=$1 [L,R,QSA]
```

However, it doesn't seem to work and I the $_GET and $_REQUEST variables in PHP are both empty, as far as I can see.

I have tried to do some debugging, including a variety of different Regexs. I also turned on mod_rewrite logging to have a look around (I'm working on a local server). These are the relevant lines:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [01/Nov/2011:12:25:55 +0100] [127.0.0.1/sid#b7843948][rid#b76d0058/subreq]   (1) [perdir /var/www/1277/] pass through /var/www/1277/showevent.php
127.0.0.1 - - [01/Nov/2011:12:25:55 +0100] [127.0.0.1/sid#b7843948][rid#b76db058/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/1277/] add path info postfix:    /var/www/1277/showevent.php -> /var/www/1277/showevent.php/1
127.0.0.1 - - [01/Nov/2011:12:25:55 +0100] [127.0.0.1/sid#b7843948][rid#b76db058/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/1277/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/1277/showevent.php/1 -> showevent.php/1
127.0.0.1 - - [01/Nov/2011:12:25:55 +0100] [127.0.0.1/sid#b7843948][rid#b76db058/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/1277/] applying pattern '^showevent/(\w+)/?$' to uri 'showevent.php/1'
127.0.0.1 - - [01/Nov/2011:12:25:55 +0100] [127.0.0.1/sid#b7843948][rid#b76db058/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/1277/] add path info postfix: /var/www/1277/showevent.php -> /var/www/1277/showevent.php/1
```

It seems that, instead of re-writing to showevents.php?id=1, it is rewriting to showevent.php/1

I would welcome any help you could give.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does happen, because of the Flags you use in your rewrite rule. You want to change

> [L,R,QSA]
>   to just "[L]"

See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteflags for reference.

Comment: Even with just [L] as a flag, it is doing the same thing (ie still rewriting to showevent.php/1)

Comment: Then maybe it's the Option "MultiViews". With MultiViews enabled in apache, "/example" evaluates to "/example.php" if that file is present. Disable it or change the rewrite-word or filename for testing purposes.